# Error having vuejs instance properties with vue-class-components and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vetur

I want to have a global var for the url of my server.

I write this on my main.ts

```
Vue.prototype.$apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
```

and then trying to use it inside App.vue

```js
console.log(this.$apiUrl)
```

I can see the url in the browser's console.

But I'm getting this error:
`Property '$apiUrl' does not exist on type 'App'.Vetur(2339)`

and I cant continue, cause in some parts of the app this.$apiUrl is undefined for some reason.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the [Class API proposal](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/17) has been abandoned. To use Vue + Typescript until Vue 3 is out, you're better off using `Vue.extend({})` component style:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue';

  export default Vue.extend({
    ...
  })
</script>
```

---

For adding global typings to your Vue instance, read [Typescript Support](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html).

Specifically, you should add this to your shims:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $apiUrl: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: :o Sad, I don't know the class-components does not go to be used in vue3... :'( Thank you

Comment: The ultimate argument (according to Evan You) is that it created more problems than it solved, specifically with Typescript (which is the main reason why it was added). If you're interested in more details, watch [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLpLYhnGqPA) where Evan touches on the subject, among other rationale and design principles behind Vue 3 and transitioning from 2.

Comment: However, [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) is currently compatible and working well with Vue 2 and it will likely be maintained at least until Vue 3 is production ready. My personal opinion is you shouldn't bother with it, as it will always struggle with more complex cases (i.e: Vuex), so your time is better spent learning Vue 3, which is written entirely in Typescript and doesn't require any workarounds for Typescript.

Comment: FWIW it sounds like vue-class-component [may still be supported](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/354) with Vue 3. I happen to be using it in my first Vue/Typescript project so that would be nice.

Comment: @totalhack, `vue-class-component` is now an independently developed plugin. It's no longer embeded into or endorsed by Vue. Which means that when you run into any implementation problem you won't be able to ask the entire Vue community about it, you'll be limited to the maintainers and users of `vue-class-component` plugin.

Comment: @tao I'll be keeping an eye on how things progress with Vue 3. I inherited vue-class-component and vue-property-decorator in a template I started my project with, but they have been straightforward and producing less verbose code than the alternative so I can't complain yet (and no problems using Vuex). I'm sure I'll see the light at some point though and switch to a more standard approach.

Comment: @total, I'm not trying to convince you of anything. In all fairness, `vue-class-component` will likely be maintained for many years to come. I also find class syntax neat and used it in a lot of projects. But I believe it would be unfair at this point to advise newcomers on using it, as it's no longer officially endorsed. Besides, as far as I'm concerned, You had a valid point when dropping it. Classes are not enough to cover all component needs. If that was the case, Angular would have been awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I need to add the $apiUrl to the types of Vue

I create a .d.ts file inside my @types folder and add the following

```
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $apiUrl: string
  }
}
```